# Saving a file in SQL Server Management Studio failed

Tags: sql-server, controlled-folder-access

I am a student... I try to save a query into a file in my documents, but I get an error message

> c:\user\my_account\documents\script.sql file not found
>   Please check the file name and try again.

Other questions:

- Generation script failed
- Can't get the list of object from the word_db
- Result error

Comment: Sounds like a network problem, you probably need to speak to your network administrator. What are you doing when you run the error *"Can't get the list of object from the word_db Resolt error"*.

Comment: sounds like you are opening a file rather than saving it ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem while trying to save a new query in SSMS 18 (after the 1903 windows update). It turned out to be windows defernder's "Controlled folder access" which was turned on. 
Solutions: turn off "controlled folder access" or whitelyst ssms (restart required)